# How to export downloaded files from Google Colab?

Tags: download, export, google-colaboratory

so , through Google_Image_Download i downloaded about 600 images , and now i'm trying to download this file locally , does anyone know how to do this ? , thank's in advance

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you observe?

Comment: well , i didn't get any error , but what i had to do is , download all the images manually one by one